# StackOverFlowError en automata

Tags: java, eclipse

El problema que tengo principalmente es que me da un error de stack overflow y no entiendo muy bien porque, por que para cada estado del autómata tengo una condición y es que un contador que voy aumentando según va pasando de estado en estado, este sea menor que el numero de caracteres que tiene la cadena que a analizar y me da la sensación de que el programa se pasa un poco esa condición por el forro de los *******.

El método pertenece sirve para que cuando la cadena pase por el autómata determinar si el estado del autómata en el que termina la secuencia es el estado final q1 y si es asi entonces la secuencia pertenece al lenguaje que lee el automata. Si tenéis alguna idea de como hacer ese método mejor también me ayudaría, porque no es perfecto tal y como esta.

```
package automatas;


public class Automata1 {

    static String cadena = "abb";
    static char[] car;
    static int cont;
    static String arbol;
    
    public static boolean comparar(char a, char b) {

        if(a==b) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            cont = 0;
            car=cadena.toCharArray();
            inicio();
            System.out.println(arbol);
            if(pertenece()) {
                System.out.println("esta palabra pertenece al lenguaje que lee el automata");
            }else {
                System.out.println("esta palabra no pertenece al lenguaje que lee el automata");
            }
            
        }catch(StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
    
    private static boolean pertenece() {
        String[] string = arbol.split(",");
        if(string[string.length-1].equals("q1")) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }



    private static void inicio() {
        q0();
        
    }
        
    private static void q0() {
        if(cont<cadena.length()) {
            switch(car[cont]) {
            case 'a':
                q1Final();
                cont++;
                break;
            case 'b':
                q3();
                cont++;
                break;
            }
            arbol += "q0,"; 
                        
        }else {
            System.out.println("El programa a terminado");
        }
    }

    private static void q1Final() {
        if(cont<cadena.length()) {
            switch(car[cont]) {
            case 'a':
                q2();
                cont++;
                break;
            case 'b':
                q0();
                cont++;
                break;
            }
            arbol += "q1,"; 
                        
        }else {
            System.out.println("El programa a terminado");
        }
    }
    private static void q2() {
        if(cont<cadena.length()) {
            switch(car[cont]) {
            case 'a':
                q3();
                cont++;
                break;
            case 'b':
                q4();
                cont++;
                break;
            }
            arbol += "q2,"; 
                        
        }else {
            System.out.println("El programa a terminado");
        }
    }
    private static void q3() {
        if(cont<cadena.length()) {
            switch(car[cont]) {
            case 'a':
                q1Final();
                cont++;
                break;
            case 'b':
                q0();
                cont++;
                break;
            }
            arbol += "q3,"; 
                        
        }else {
            System.out.println("El programa a terminado");
        }
    }
    private static void q4() {
        if(cont<cadena.length()) {
            switch(car[cont]) {
            case 'a':
                q3();
                cont++;
                break;
            case 'b':
                q4();
                cont++;
                break;
            }
            arbol += "q4,"; 
                        
        }else {
            System.out.println("El programa a terminado");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Bueno no se si he explicado muy bien mi problema. Este es básicamente que al poner la cadena "abb"(no es solo con esta cadena, es solo para poner un ejemplo) no se para al moverse 3 estados, sino que continua indefinidamente hasta que da el error stack overflow.

Comment: El `StackOverflowError` se da porque se llena la pila de llamadas a métodos. Lee un poco más sobre ello porque mi explicación es muy escueta y no da para explicarlo en un comentario. Básicamente tu error se da porque `q1Final` llama a `q2`, `q2` llama a `q3` y `q3` llama a `q1Final` repitiéndose el ciclo de llamadas hasta que se llena la pila. No estás aumentando `cont` en ningún momento. De paso si ya conoces sobre recursividad, aplícala que los métodos son prácticamente iguales.

Comment: Muchas gracias Glenn no me habia dado cuenta de ese detalle